# Golfing at the Bank

Tags: code-golf

Our new bank needs a teller transaction system but there is a problem. There is
only a few hundred bytes of space left on our server, so you will have to write
very compact code.

### Database

Thankfully our database is very simple (it was built by the schoolboy son of our
bank president), and we only have a few customers so far.

file `Bank.data` is:

```
Account Firstname Lastname Balance Date
123 Maree Jones 346.22 2014-12-13
035 Thomas Breakbone 3422.02 2015-01-03
422 Henrietta Throsby-Borashenko 277847.74 2014-11-21
501 Timmy Bongo 7.95 2014-11-04
105 William Greene 893.00 2015-01-06
300 Mary Galoway 1228.73 2014-12-28
203 Samantha Richardson 2055.44 2014-11-01
151 Bruce Wayne 956119.66 2014-10-09
166 Chip Stonesmith 266.71 2014-12-15
888 Alexandria Cooper 1299.82 2014-12-30
```

### Application Specification

Our bank application must implement the following commands:

`open <firstname> <lastname>`
Creates (opens) a new account printing a unique 3 digit account number.

`withdraw <account> <amount>`
Withdraw amount from an account.

`deposit <account> <amount>`
Deposit amount into an account.

`close <account>`
Close account if empty.

`report <fieldname>`
Print a report of the database sorted by fieldname. Move the fieldname column
to the first position. Each column width will be the maximum of the widest data
and fieldname width, separated by one space. The first line will be the field
titles. The balances only must be right justified with a leading `$` sign.

`print <account>`
Print the fieldnames and record for this account formated like the report.

Each time a record is changed, the `Date` field in the record must be updated to
the current date.

The application will show a "# " prompt when waiting for a command. If a command
fails (such as an operation on an unknown account or insufficient funds), the
application must print the informative error message "failed". The program must
write changes back to the file after each change, and read from the file on each
command as there are many teller programs around the world operating on the file
concurrently (we don't need file locking - that may reduce performance).

**EDIT:** String fields are simple ASCII (a-z,A-Z,-) without white space and the amount will always be between 0.00 and 1000000000.00 (1 billion) dollars with 2 decimal places indicating cents. The date will be in local time at each branch (a simple solution but may lead to some problems later...).

### Output

Answers will need to demonstrate that they meet the specification. Please attach the output from your program after processing the following commands:

```
report Balance
open Clark Kent
print 001
deposit 001 4530
withdraw 105 893
close 105
report Date
```

Ensure you use an original copy of the `Bank.data` file given above.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so your score will be the byte count of your code. Standard
loopholes are prohibited.

Comment: Should be a way to exit program?

Comment: We don't want to pack too many features into this application ;-) A control-C type exit is fine.

Comment: What constraints may be assumed on the characters in `<firstname>` and `<lastname>` and the range and precision of `<amount>`? (E.g. there may be some optimisations which are possible if `<amount>` always has exactly two decimal places - or you may want the program to be usable by the Middle Eastern branch, where most currencies use three decimal places).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have added some clauses on string type and amount range as suggested.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit in my question about the names. The most useful restriction would be that `<firstname>` and `<lastname>` both only use `a-zA-Z`, but even a simple statement that they never contain tab characters allows using TSV. If they could be any sequence of ASCII characters, some form of escaping or delimiting other than with a one-char delimiter is necessary.

Comment: Oops. Got it now. Edited to answer your question. There is no white space in any fields. Data fields are separated by a single space.

Comment: So your server only has a hundred bytes left for a program, but it contains a 4MB Golfscript interpreter? Not to mention the whole python library, which is over 100MB. Just saying :)

Comment: It does sound a bit contrived doesn't it. Then again, I think you have spotted a flaw in this whole site. Where in the real world would you need to write golfed code?

Comment: This kind of looks like a homework assignment, just my 2¢…

Comment: It's a long long time since I have been in school. I will take your comment to mean that the problem is very clearly written so that even first year computer science students can understand it ;-)

Comment: Can I assume that Bank.data already exists and is in the proper format?

Comment: Yes. The initial Bank.data file is given in the question. You can assume your program has access to this file in the current directory (or anywhere else you would like).

Comment: Can I assume the file headers are only there for reference? ;)

Comment: The titles in the first line of the file must be maintained (thats what you get when you take on a cheap DBA ;-)

Comment: I have never golfed anything more in my entire life... O.O

Comment: I failed to make explicit that you need to show the output from your program. I have added the *Output* section to the question. You will _not_ need to change your code. Just add the output of your program to your answer. It is the only way I can tell if they work as advertised ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ruby, 918

This question is quite long to golf as it consists of many small parts. For a moment, I almost wanted to define some additional classes to make things neater with polymorphism etc... (but in the end I didn't).

```ruby
l=->a,i{a.map{|x|x[i].to_s.size}.max}
y=1..-1
d=File.open(f="bank.data").each.map(&:split)
j=[k=%w{Account Firstname Lastname Balance Date}]
_=->{puts"Failure"}
q=->t,v=0{z=-1;puts t.map{|r|([v]+((0..4).to_a-[v])).map{|c|b=l[t,c];c!=3?r[c].ljust(b):(?$*(z+=z<1?1:0)+r[c]).rjust(b>7?b+1:b)}*' '}}
w=->d{File.open(f,?w).write(d.map{|x|x*' '}*?\n)}
s=->i,m=!0{o=d.select{|r|r[0]==i};o==[]?_[]:m ?q[[k]+o]:1}
u=->{Time.now.to_s[0..9]}
($><<"# ";i=gets.split;o=i.size;("report"==h=i[0])?((v=k.index i[1])?q[j+d[y].sort_by{|x|v!=3?x[v]:x[v].to_f},v]:_[]):h=="print"?s[i[1],0]:h=="close"?(s[m=i[1]]?w[d=j+d[y].select{|r|r[0]!=m}]:0):h=="open"?((o==3&&t=((1..999).map{|x|'%03d'%x}-d.map{|x|x[0]})[0])?(w[d=d+[[t,i[1],i[2],'0.00',u[]]]];puts t):_[]):h=="withdraw"||h=="deposit"?(o==3&&s[i[1]]?w[d=j+d[y].map{|r|i[1]==r[0]?(b=(c=r[3].to_f)+i[2].to_f*(i[0][0]==?w?-1:1);0>b&&(b=c;_[]);r[0..2]+["%.2f"%b,u[]]):r}]:_[]):_[])while 1
```

Probably can be golfed further. 
But as of now, I can't even keep track of what I did in the last line.

Output:

```ruby
# report Balance
   Balance Account Firstname  Lastname           Date      
     $7.95 501     Timmy      Bongo              2014-11-04
   $266.71 166     Chip       Stonesmith         2014-12-15
   $346.22 123     Maree      Jones              2014-12-13
   $893.00 105     William    Greene             2015-01-06
  $1228.73 300     Mary       Galoway            2014-12-28
  $1299.82 888     Alexandria Cooper             2014-12-30
  $2055.44 203     Samantha   Richardson         2014-11-01
  $3422.02 035     Thomas     Breakbone          2015-01-03
$277847.74 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko 2014-11-21
$956119.66 151     Bruce      Wayne              2014-10-09
# open Clark Kent
001
# print 001
Account Firstname Lastname Balance Date      
001     Clark     Kent       $0.00 2015-02-01
# deposit 001 4530
# withdraw 105 893
# close 105
# report Date
Date       Account Firstname  Lastname              Balance
2014-10-09 151     Bruce      Wayne              $956119.66
2014-11-01 203     Samantha   Richardson           $2055.44
2014-11-04 501     Timmy      Bongo                   $7.95
2014-11-21 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko $277847.74
2014-12-13 123     Maree      Jones                 $346.22
2014-12-15 166     Chip       Stonesmith            $266.71
2014-12-28 300     Mary       Galoway              $1228.73
2014-12-30 888     Alexandria Cooper               $1299.82
2015-01-03 035     Thomas     Breakbone            $3422.02
2015-02-01 001     Clark      Kent                 $4530.00
#
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Comment: I kno this is a byproduct of misapplied syntax highlighting, but the dollar amounts look so cool with the whole numbers in black and the cents in pale red.

Answer (score 2):

## Cobra - 1505

```cobra
class P
    var m='Account Firstname Lastname Balance Date'
    def main
        while[d=DateTime.now.toString('yyyy-MM-dd'),z='0.00']
            print'#'stop
            try,branch (c=Console.readLine.split)[r=0]
                on'open'
                    post while u in for x in.f get x[0],u=(r+=1).toString('000')
                    print u
                    .f=.f.toList+[@[u,c[1],c[2],z,d]]
                on'deposit'or 'withdraw'
                    n=.z(if(c[0]>'deposit','-','')+c[2])
                    assert.z(.i(c[1])[3])+n>=0
                    .f=for x in.f get if(x[0]==c[1],@[x[:3].join(' '),'[(.z(x[3])+n).toString(z)]',d],x)
                on'close'
                    assert.i(c[1])[3]==z
                    .f=for x in.f where.i(c[1])<>x
                on'report',.a(.f,c[1])
                on'print',.a([.i(c[1])])
                else,assert 0
            catch
                print'failed'
    def z(s='')as float
        return float.parse(s)
    pro f as String[]?*
        get
            return for x in File.readAllLines('Bank.data')[1:]get x.split
        set
            File.writeAllLines('Bank.data',[.m]+for x in value get x.join(' '))
    def a(f as String[]?*,c='Account')
        i,l=(m=.m.split).toList.indexOf(c),[7,9,8,8,4]
        assert c in m
        print (for q in (for z in (for x in[m]+f.toList.sorted(do(a as String[],b as String[]))get for y in 5 get[t=try' '.repeat(l[y]-x[y].length)catch get'',if(y-3,x[y]+t,t+if(x==m,' ','$')+x[y])][1])get[z[i]]+for p in z where p<>z[i])get q.join(' ')).join('\n')
            for v in[a,b],for k in 5,if (u=v[k].length)>l[k],l[k]=u
            return[d=a[i].compareTo(b[i]),d,d,.z(a[3]).compareTo(.z(b[3])),DateTime.parse(a[4]).compareTo(DateTime.parse(b[4]))][i]
    def i(s='')as String[]?
        return (for x in.f where x[0]==s)[0]
```

Output:

```
#report Balance
   Balance Account Firstname  Lastname           Date      
     $7.95 501     Timmy      Bongo              2014-11-04
   $266.71 166     Chip       Stonesmith         2014-12-15
   $346.22 123     Maree      Jones              2014-12-13
   $893.00 105     William    Greene             2015-01-06
  $1228.73 300     Mary       Galoway            2014-12-28
  $1299.82 888     Alexandria Cooper             2014-12-30
  $2055.44 203     Samantha   Richardson         2014-11-01
  $3422.02 035     Thomas     Breakbone          2015-01-03
$277847.74 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko 2014-11-21
$956119.66 151     Bruce      Wayne              2014-10-09
#open Clark Kent
001
#print 001
Account Firstname Lastname   Balance Date
001     Clark     Kent         $0.00 2015-02-04
#deposit 001 4530
#withdraw 105 893
#close 105
#report Date
Date       Account Firstname  Lastname              Balance
2014-10-09 151     Bruce      Wayne              $956119.66
2014-11-01 203     Samantha   Richardson           $2055.44
2014-11-04 501     Timmy      Bongo                   $7.95
2014-11-21 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko $277847.74
2014-12-13 123     Maree      Jones                 $346.22
2014-12-15 166     Chip       Stonesmith            $266.71
2014-12-28 300     Mary       Galoway              $1228.73
2014-12-30 888     Alexandria Cooper               $1299.82
2015-01-03 035     Thomas     Breakbone            $3422.02
2015-02-04 001     Clark      Kent                 $4530.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your entry. I had to look up Cobra to see what it was. It might be time for me to learn another language.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Comment: @CarpetPython will be done this afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL 1919

Called with "exec q 'Your command here'" I don't think T-SQL can actually get user input, so I think this is as close as it can be.

Uses the bcp utility for I/O which I haven't tried before because it comes with SQL Server 2014.

I'm not sure if it would be better or worse to use only the main stored procedure and put the rest of the code in there.

```
CREATE PROC q @ CHAR(99)AS
CREATE TABLE ##(A CHAR(3),F CHAR(99),L CHAR(99),B MONEY,D DATE)bcp ## in Bank.data -t " " -T
DECLARE @g INT,@w MONEY,@z CHAR(9),@y CHAR(99),@x CHAR(99)SET @g=patindex('% %',@)SET @z=substring(@,1,@g-1)SET @=substring(@,@g+1,99)SET @g=patindex('% %',@)SET @y=substring(@,1,@g-1)SET @=substring(@,@g+1,99)SET @g=patindex('% %',@)SET @x=substring(@,1,@g-1)SET @w=CONVERT(MONEY,@x)*2*(LEN(@z)-7.5)IF @z='open'exec o @y,@x
IF @z='close'exec c @y
IF @z='withdraw'exec w @y,@w
IF @z='deposit'exec w @y,@w
IF @z='print'exec p @y
IF @z='report'exec r @y
bcp ## out Bank.data -t " " -T
SELECT'#'
CREATE PROC r @q CHAR(9)AS
DECLARE @a char(9)='A Account',@f char(11)='F Firstname',@l char(10)='L Lastname',@b char(45)='CONCAT(''$'',SPACE(9-LEN(B)),B) Balance',@d char(6)='D Date',@ varchar(999)='SELECT '
IF @q='Account'SET @+=@a+','+@f+','+@l+','+@b+','+@d
IF @q='Balance'SET @+=@b+','+@a+','+@f+','+@l+','+@d
IF @q='Date'SET @+=@d+','+@a+','+@f+','+@l+','+@b
IF @q='Lastname'SET @+=@l+','+@a+','+@f+','+@b+','+@d
IF @q='Firstname'SET @+=@f+','+@a+','+@l+','+@b+','+@d
IF LEN(@)<9
BEGIN
SELECT'failed'RETURN
END
SET @+=' FROM ## ORDER BY '+@q
exec(@)CREATE PROC p @ CHAR(3)AS
DECLARE @r CHAR(9)=(SELECT 1 FROM ## WHERE A=@)IF @r IS NULL SELECT'failed'ELSE SELECT*FROM ## WHERE A=@
CREATE Proc o @f CHAR(99),@l CHAR(99)AS
DECLARE @ INT=0,@r CHAR(9)=(SELECT 1 FROM # WHERE A='000')WHILE @r IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

SET @+=1
SET @r=(SELECT 1 FROM # WHERE CONVERT(INT,A)=@)END
IF @>999 SELECT'failed'ELSE INSERT INTO # OUTPUT Inserted.A VALUES(REPLICATE('0',3-LEN(@))+CONVERT(CHAR(3),@),@f,@l,0,GETDATE())CREATE PROC w @ CHAR(3),@b MONEY AS
DECLARE @r CHAR(9)=(SELECT 1 FROM ## WHERE A=@ AND B>@b)IF @r IS NULL SELECT'failed'ELSE UPDATE ## SET B=B-@b,D=GETDATE()WHERE A=@
CREATE Proc c @q CHAR(3)AS
DECLARE @r CHAR(9)=(SELECT 1 FROM ## WHERE A=@q AND B=0)IF @r IS NULL SELECT'failed'ELSE DELETE FROM ## WHERE A=@q
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2 - 2205 bytes

Here is a rather verbose attempt at a solution.

```python
import sys, time, re
def db(recs):
    text = '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in [titles]+recs)
    open('Bank.data', 'wt').write(text+'\n')
def wid(col, recs):
    w = max(len(r[col]) for r in [titles]+recs)
    return w if col == 3 else -w
while 1:
    inp=raw_input('# ').split()
    try:
        cmd = inp.pop(0)
        data = [d.split() for d in open('Bank.data', 'rt').readlines()]
        titles = data.pop(0)
        today = '-'.join('%02u' % v for v in time.localtime()[:3])
        alist = set(int(r[0]) for r in data)
        if cmd == 'open':
            assert re.match(r'[-a-zA-Z]{2,}', inp[0]+inp[1])
            acct = '%03u'%([n for n in range(1, 1000) if n not in alist][0])
            rec = [acct] + inp + ['0.00', today]
            db(data+[rec])
            print acct
        elif cmd == 'withdraw':
            a, m = inp[0], float(inp[1])
            rec = [r for r in data if r[0] == a][0]
            b = float(rec[3])
            assert b >= m
            rec[3] = '%.2f' % (b-m)
            rec[4] = today
            db(data)
        elif cmd == 'deposit':
            a, m = inp[0], float(inp[1])
            rec=[r for r in data if r[0]==a][0]
            rec[3]='%.2f'%(float(rec[3])+m)
            rec[4]=today
            db(data)
        elif cmd=='close':
            rec=[r for r in data if r[0]==inp[0]][0]
            assert int(rec[3])==0
            data=[r for r in data if r!=rec]
            db(data)
        elif cmd=='report':
            for r in data: r[3]='$'+r[3]
            fmtlist=['%'+str(wid(c,data))+'s' for c in range(5)]
            loc=titles.index(inp[0])
            for r in data: r.insert(0,r.pop(loc))
            data.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[0][1:]) if loc==3 else x[0])
            titles.insert(0,titles.pop(loc))
            fmtlist.insert(0,fmtlist.pop(loc))
            for r in [titles]+data: print ' '.join(fmtlist)%tuple(r)
        elif cmd=='print':
            for r in data: r[3]='$'+r[3]
            rec=[r for r in data if r[0]==inp[0]][0]
            fmt=' '.join('%'+str(wid(c,[rec]))+'s' for c in range(5))
            for r in [titles,rec]: print fmt%tuple(r)
        else: raise()
    except:
        print 'failed'
```

Here is a sample of the application in use:

```python
# report Balance
   Balance Account Firstname  Lastname           Date      
     $7.95 501     Timmy      Bongo              2014-11-04
   $266.71 166     Chip       Stonesmith         2014-12-15
   $346.22 123     Maree      Jones              2014-12-13
   $893.00 105     William    Greene             2015-01-06
  $1228.73 300     Mary       Galoway            2014-12-28
  $1299.82 888     Alexandria Cooper             2014-12-30
  $2055.44 203     Samantha   Richardson         2014-11-01
  $3422.02 035     Thomas     Breakbone          2015-01-03
$277847.74 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko 2014-11-21
$956119.66 151     Bruce      Wayne              2014-10-09
# open Clark Kent
001
# print 001
Account Firstname Lastname Balance Date      
001     Clark     Kent       $0.00 2015-01-13
# deposit 001 4530
# withdraw 105 893
# close 105
# report Date
Date       Account Firstname  Lastname              Balance
2014-10-09 151     Bruce      Wayne              $956119.66
2014-11-01 203     Samantha   Richardson           $2055.44
2014-11-04 501     Timmy      Bongo                   $7.95
2014-11-21 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko $277847.74
2014-12-13 123     Maree      Jones                 $346.22
2014-12-15 166     Chip       Stonesmith            $266.71
2014-12-28 300     Mary       Galoway              $1228.73
2014-12-30 888     Alexandria Cooper               $1299.82
2015-01-03 035     Thomas     Breakbone            $3422.02
2015-01-13 001     Clark      Kent                 $4530.00
#
```

Answer (score 1):

### STATA 1506

Didn't try to golf it too much. I figured a statistical language would be better at this, but apparently.

```
set more off
while 1<2{
qui insheet using Bank.data,delim(" ")clear case
form A %-03.0f
form B %10.2f
form D %-10s
form F %-50s
form L %-50s
g K="$"+string(B,"%10.2f")
di"#",_r(q)
loc s: di %tdCCYY-NN-DD date(c(current_date),"DMY")
if word("$q",1)=="open"{
forv x=0/999{
egen c=anymatch(A),v(`x')
if c<1{
egen m=min(A)
cap expand 2 if A==m,gen(z)
replace A=`x' if A==m&z>0
replace B=0 if A==`x'
replace F=word("$q",2) if A==`x'
replace L=word("$q",3) if A==`x'
replace D="`s'" if A==`x'
di"`x'"
outsheet A-D using Bank.data,delim(" ")replace
continue, br
}
if `x'==999{
di"failed"
}
drop c
}
continue
}
if word("$q",1)=="report"{
ren B R
ren K Balance
if word("$q",2)=="Account"{
so A
l A-L B D,clean noo
}
else if word("$q",2)=="Date"{
so D
l D A-L B,clean noo
}
else if word("$q",2)=="Lastname"{
so L
l L A F B D,clean noo
}
else if word("$q",2)=="Balance"{
so R
l B A-L D,clean noo
}
else if word("$q",2)=="Firstname"{
so F
l F A L B D,clean noo
}
else{
di"failed"
}
continue
}
gen i=real(word("$q",2))
egen p=min(abs(A-i))
if p>0{
di"failed"
continue
}
if word("$q",1)=="close"{
egen c=count(i)
drop if A==i&B==0
qui cou
if c==r(N){
di"failed"
continue
}
}
if word("$q",1)=="print"{
drop Balance
ren K Balance
l A-L B D if A==i,noo clean ab(9)
continue
}
gen j=real(word("$q",3))
if word("$q",1)=="withdraw"{
replace B=B-j if A==i
egen c=min(B)
if c<0{
di"failed"
continue
}
}
if word("$q",1)=="deposit"{
replace B=B+j if A==i
}
replace D="`s'" if A==i
outsheet A-D using Bank.data,delim(" ")replace
}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch - 1827

Batch is not built for this kind of thing.

```
@echo off&setLocal enableDelayedExpansion&set B=Bank.data&echo wscript.echo eval(wscript.arguments(0))>%temp%\eval1.vbs&set Z=goto :EOF&set V=call&set F=for /l %%a in (1,1,
:m
set C=-1&set D=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%
for /f "tokens=1-5" %%a in (%B%)do set/aC+=1 &set !C!=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e&set !C!n=%%a&set !C!f=%%b&set !C!s=%%c&set !C!b=%%d&set !C!d=%%e&set A=%%a&set/aA+=1
set/pI="#"
%V% :%I% 2>nul||echo failed&goto m
goto m
:open
echo %A% %1 %2 0.00 %D%>>%B%&echo %A%&%Z%
:close
echo !0!>%B%&%F%!C!)do if "!%%an!" NEQ "%1" (echo !%%a!>>%B%)else if !%%ab! GTR 0.00 echo failed & echo !%%a!>>%B%
%Z%
:deposit
%F%!C!)do if "!%%an!"=="%1" set p=%%a
%V% :c "!%p%b!+%2"
set %p%b=%r%&set %p%d=%D%&%V% :u
%Z%
:withdraw
%F%!C!)do if "!%%an!"=="%1" set p=%%a
%V% :c "!%p%b!-%2"&if "%r:~0,1%"=="-" echo failed&%Z%
set %p%b=%r%&set %p%d=%D%&%V% :u
%Z%
:report
for /l %%a in (1,1,50)do set H= !H!
for /l %%a in (0,1,!C!)do (
%V% :l !%%an!&set %%anl=!l!&if !l! GTR !tn! set/atn=!l!
%V% :l !%%af!&set %%afl=!l!&if !l! GTR !tf! set/atf=!l!
%V% :l !%%as!&set %%asl=!l!&if !l! GTR !ts! set/ats=!l!
%V% :l !%%ab!&set %%abl=!l!&if !l! GTR !tb! set/atb=!l!
)
for /l %%a in (0,1,!C!)do %V% :c "%tn%-!%%anl!"&set sn=!r:~0,-3!&%V% :t !sn!&set pn=!x!&%V% :c "%tf%-!%%afl!"&set sf=!r:~0,-3!&%V% :t !sf!&set pf=!x!&%V% :c "%ts%-!%%asl!"&set ss=!r:~0,-3!&%V% :t !ss!&set ps=!x!&%V% :c "%tb%-!%%abl!"&set sb=!r:~0,-3!&%V% :t !sb!&set pb=!x!&echo !%%an!!pn! !%%af!!pf! !%%as!!ps! !pb!$!%%ab! !%%ad!
%Z%
:l
set S=%1&for /f usebackq %%a in (`Powershell "'!S!'.Length"`)do set l=%%a
%Z%
:t
set x=!H:~0,%1!
%Z%
:u
echo !0!>%B%&%F%!C!)do echo !%%an! !%%af! !%%as! !%%ab! !%%ad!>>%B%&%Z%
:c
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo %temp%\eval1.vbs "round(%1,2)"')do set r=%%a
if "%r:~-3,1%" NEQ "." set r=%r%.00
```

Yet to implement Sort (within report), and Print functions.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <strike>1952</strike> 1883

I will show some output when I get in tomorrow. For now, here's the submission:

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.IO;using System.Linq;using S=System.String;using O=System.Func<dynamic,string,string>;class I{char[]c={' '};Action<string>w;Func<S,S,S,S,S,dynamic>n;Func<string>N;List<dynamic>T;private static void Main(string[]a){while(true){Console.Write("# ");new I().Parse(Console.ReadLine());}}I(){w=Console.WriteLine;n=(g,h,i,j,k)=>new{a=g,f=h,l=i,b=j,d=k};N=()=>DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");}List<dynamic>G(){return File.ReadAllLines("test.data").Select(l=>l.Split(c)).Select(ac=>n(ac[0],ac[1],ac[2],ac[3],ac[4])).ToList();}void W(){File.WriteAllLines("test.data",T.Select(a=>(S)(a.a+" "+a.f+" "+a.l+" "+a.b+" "+a.d)));}void Parse(string inp){var C=true;try{Func<object,float>v=Convert.ToSingle;Func<string,bool>s=string.IsNullOrEmpty;var i=inp.Split(c);T=G();Func<S,int>F=m=>T.IndexOf(T.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.a==m));C=!s(i[1]);var g=F(i[1]);switch(i[0]){case"open":if(C){int an=0;var cs="000";while(T.Any(A=>cs==A.a)){an++;cs=an.ToString("D3");}T.Add(n(cs,i[1],i[2],"0.00",N()));w(cs);}break;case"withdraw":case"deposit":var D=i[0]=="deposit";C=(D||v(T[g].b)>=v(i[2]));var ba=(v(T[g].b)+v(i[2])*(D?1:-1)).ToString("F");if(C)T[g]=n(T[g].a,T[g].f,T[g].l,ba,N());break;case"close":C=g>-1&&v(T[g].b)<=0;if(C)T.RemoveAt(g);break;case"report":case"print":var X=i[0]=="print";var B=1;O o=(x,p)=>((Type)x.GetType()).GetProperty(p).GetValue(x);O K=(k,j)=>{var r=(j=="b"?"$":"");var P=T.Max(_=>(o(_,j)).Length);return r==""?(o(k,j)).PadRight(P):((B<1?r:"")+(o(k,j))).PadLeft(P+1);};var q=i[1];Action<dynamic,S>U=(u,t)=>{S l=""; foreach(var h in t)l+=K(u,h.ToString())+" "; w(l);};q=q=="Account"?"a":q=="Firstname"?"f":q=="Lastname"?"l":q=="Balance"?"b":q=="Date"?"d":"a"; var V=(q+"afldb".Replace(q,""));U(T.First(),V);B=0;foreach(var M in(X?T.Skip(1).Take(1):T.Skip(1).OrderBy(df=>o(df,q))))U(M,V);break;}W();}catch{}if(!C)w("Failed");}}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could add a sample of the program output (see updated question). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**C# - <strike>1870</strike> 1881 Bytes**

Abusing `using` aliases, `Action`, `Func`, exceptions for flow control and more.  Was considering exploiting that "report" didn't specify how things should be sorted.  Bank.data must use unix line breaks or this code will break.

Edited to fix a potential issue sorting by fields other than Date and Balance.

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.IO;using System.Linq;using Ac=System.Action;using Cn=System.Console;using F1=System.Func<string,int>;using F2=System.Func<string>;using S=System.String;class P{static void Main(S[] args){S fn="Bank.data";List<S>ad=null;F1 L=(s)=>s.Length;F2 dt=()=>S.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",DateTime.Now);Func<S,S[]>sp=(s)=>s.Split(' ');Action<S,S>wl=(s,fm)=>Cn.WriteLine(S.Format(fm,sp(s)));Func<S,S>rs=(s)=>{var t=sp(s);t[3]="$"+t[3];return S.Join(" ",t);};F2 fs=()=>{int[]sz={7,9,8,7};ad.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(b=>{for(int c=0;c<4;c++){sz[c]=Math.Max(sz[c],L(sp(rs(b))[c]));}});return"{0,-"+sz[0]+"} {1,-"+sz[1]+"} {2,-"+sz[2]+"} {3,"+sz[3]+"} {4,-10}";};F1 k=(s)=>sp(ad[0]).ToList().FindIndex(a=>a==s);Ac Sv=()=>File.WriteAllText(fn,S.Join("\n",ad));Ac Ld=()=>ad=File.ReadAllText(fn).Split('\n').ToList();Action<int,S>R=(r,a)=>{var s=sp(ad[r]);s[3]=S.Format("{0:#.00}",Convert.ToDouble(s[3])+Convert.ToDouble(a));s[4]=dt();ad[r]=S.Join(" ",s);};Ac f=()=>wl("failure","{0}");F1 ri=(n)=>{for(int w=1;w < ad.Count;w++){if(ad[w].StartsWith(n))return w;}return -1;};F2 nm=()=>{var s="";for(int i=1;i<1000;i++){s=S.Format("{0:000}",i);if (ri(s)<0)break;}return s;};for(;;){Cn.Write("# ");S i=Cn.ReadLine();var it=sp(i+" ");Ld();var n=ri(it[1]);it=sp(i);var a=new Dictionary<S,Ac>(){{"deposit",()=>R(n,it[2])},{"withdraw",()=>R(n,"-"+it[2])},{"close",()=>(sp(ad[n])[3]==".00"?()=>ad.RemoveAt(n):f)()},{"open",()=>{var nn=nm();ad.Add(S.Format("{0} {1} {2} .00 {3}",nn,it[1],it[2],dt()));wl(nn,"{0}");}},{"print",()=>{wl(ad[0],fs());wl(rs(ad[n]),fs());}},{"report",()=>{var ks=sp(fs()).ToList();var ki=k(it[1]);ks.Insert(0,ks[ki]);ks.RemoveAt(ki+1);var kf=S.Join(" ",ks);wl(ad[0],kf);ad.Skip(1).OrderBy(b=>(ki==3?new S('0',11-L(sp(b)[ki])):"")+sp(b)[ki]).ToList().ForEach(b=>wl(rs(b),kf));}}};try{a[it[0]]();Sv();}catch(Exception){f();}}}}
```

Output:

```
# report Balance
   Balance Account Firstname  Lastname           Date
     $7.95 501     Timmy      Bongo              2014-11-04
   $266.71 166     Chip       Stonesmith         2014-12-15
   $346.22 123     Maree      Jones              2014-12-13
   $893.00 105     William    Greene             2015-01-06
  $1228.73 300     Mary       Galoway            2014-12-28
  $1299.82 888     Alexandria Cooper             2014-12-30
  $2055.44 203     Samantha   Richardson         2014-11-01
  $3422.02 035     Thomas     Breakbone          2015-01-03
$277847.74 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko 2014-11-21
$956119.66 151     Bruce      Wayne              2014-10-09
# open Clark Kent
001
# print 001
Account Firstname  Lastname              Balance Date
001     Clark      Kent                     $.00 2015-02-03
# deposit 001 4530
# withdraw 105 893
# close 105
# report Date
Date       Account Firstname  Lastname              Balance
2014-10-09 151     Bruce      Wayne              $956119.66
2014-11-01 203     Samantha   Richardson           $2055.44
2014-11-04 501     Timmy      Bongo                   $7.95
2014-11-21 422     Henrietta  Throsby-Borashenko $277847.74
2014-12-13 123     Maree      Jones                 $346.22
2014-12-15 166     Chip       Stonesmith            $266.71
2014-12-28 300     Mary       Galoway              $1228.73
2014-12-30 888     Alexandria Cooper               $1299.82
2015-01-03 035     Thomas     Breakbone            $3422.02
2015-02-03 001     Clark      Kent                 $4530.00
#
```